# JSF show a p:dialog if a parameter is true

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

So what I want to do is quit simple. I have an page that displays a list of users, for example adminUsers.jsf, and it has a list of the users.  I click the New User button and modal p:dialog shows with the user form.

This works perfect but what I want do is allowing my users to click on a link and the adminUsers.jsf shows with the p:dialog enabled.

So if a Users goes to the url

```
http://localhost:8080/pages/adminUser.jsf?create=true
```

the modal dialog is shown without clicking any extra button.
I thought of a way of doing that but maybe it is not the proper JSF way.
So this is what I am thinking.
Capture the "create" on my userAdminController, and set an

```
<h:outputText/>
```

write some javascript to call userPanel.show, with a param like this.

```
rendered="#{usuarioAdminController.create}"
```

Is this the correct way of doing this.

Comment: I doubt the usefulness of your design. A sensitive operation like a login should not be controlled by a parameter that's visible in the url. It allows too much control on the part of the user.

Comment: it is not a login, on the dialog there is a form to edit the users, i already limited the access to the userAdmin.jsf on web.xml.  It is really on a folder /pages/admin/userAdmin.jsf, and /pages/admin/* has limited access.  I am using other forms the user case was just an example. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the value request parameter directly to the `visible` attribute of the dialog like this:

```
<p:dialog visible="#{param.create}"/>
```